# Extract value in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

My Code:

```
import requests
import json

web_page = requests.get("http://api.bart.gov/api/etd.aspx?cmd=etd&orig=mont&key=MW9S-E7SL-26DU-VV8V&json=y")
response = web_page.text
parsed_json = json.loads(response)
#print(parsed_json)

print(parsed_json['root']['date'])
print(parsed_json['root']['time'])
print(parsed_json['root']['station']['name'])
```

How to extract value of destination and minutes from below in Python.

```
[{'name': 'Montgomery St.', 'abbr': 'MONT', 'etd': [{'destination': 'Daly City', 'abbreviation': 'DALY', 'limited': '0', 'estimate': [{'minutes': '39', 'platform': '1', 'direction': 'South', 'length': '10', 'color': 'WHITE', 'hexcolor': '#ffffff', 'bikeflag': '1', 'delay': '220'}]}, {'destination': 'SF Airport', 'abbreviation': 'SFIA', 'limited': '0', 'estimate': [{'minutes': '16', 'platform': '1', 'direction': 'South', 'length': '10', 'color': 'YELLOW', 'hexcolor': '#ffff33', 'bikeflag': '1', 'delay': '132'}, {'minutes': '26', 'platform': '1', 'direction': 'South', 'length': '10', 'color': 'BLUE', 'hexcolor': '#0099cc', 'bikeflag': '1', 'delay': '69'}]}]}]
```

Comment: Am I missing anything? where is `station` in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `parsed_json['root']['station']['name']`. `parsed_json['root']['station']` is a list, not a dict, so it doesn't have `name` key. You need to use index 0 or iterate over it

```
for station in parsed_json['root']['station']:
    for etd in station['etd']:
        for estimate in etd['estimate']:
            print(etd['destination'], estimate['minutes'])
```

Output

```
Daly City 35
SF Airport 16
SF Airport 26
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
json_obj = {'name': 'Montgomery St.', 'abbr': 'MONT', 'etd': [{'destination': 'Antioch', 'abbreviation': 'ANTC', 'limited': '0', 'estimate': [{'minutes': '1', 'platform': '2', 'direction': 'North', 'length': '10', 'color': 'YELLOW', 'hexcolor': '#ffff33', 'bikeflag': '1', 'delay': '254'}]}, 

{'destination': 'Daly City', 'abbreviation': 'DALY', 'limited': '0', 'estimate': [{'minutes': '39', 'platform': '1', 'direction': 'South', 'length': '0', 'color': 'BLUE', 'hexcolor': '#0099cc', 'bikeflag': '1', 'delay': '0'}]}, 

{'destination': 'SF Airport', 'abbreviation': 'SFIA', 'limited': '0', 'estimate': [{'minutes': '38', 'platform': '1', 'direction': 'South', 'length': '10', 'color': 'YELLOW', 'hexcolor': '#ffff33', 'bikeflag': '1', 'delay': '0'}]}]}

for item in json_obj['etd']:
    dest = item['destination']
    minute = item['estimate'][0]['minutes']
    print(dest, minute)
```

Output:

```
Antioch 1
Daly City 39
SF Airport 38
```

Comment: Thank You Sayandip for your response. But, can you check the new format which I have pasted in edited question. The response I am getting when using "parsed_json['root']['station']" is in list format.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is in d_MONT:

```
d_MONT = {'name': 'Montgomery St.', 'abbr': 'MONT', 'etd': [{'destination': 'Antioch', 'abbreviation': 'ANTC', 'limited': '0', 'estimate': [{'minutes': '1', 'platform': '2', 'direction': 'North', 'length': '10', 'color': 'YELLOW', 'hexcolor': '#ffff33', 'bikeflag': '1', 'delay': '254'}]}, 

{'destination': 'Daly City', 'abbreviation': 'DALY', 'limited': '0', 'estimate': [{'minutes': '39', 'platform': '1', 'direction': 'South', 'length': '0', 'color': 'BLUE', 'hexcolor': '#0099cc', 'bikeflag': '1', 'delay': '0'}]}, 

{'destination': 'SF Airport', 'abbreviation': 'SFIA', 'limited': '0', 'estimate': [{'minutes': '38', 'platform': '1', 'direction': 'South', 'length': '10', 'color': 'YELLOW', 'hexcolor': '#ffff33', 'bikeflag': '1', 'delay': '0'}]}]}
```

This will find the next train to destinationRequired:

```
destinationList = d_MONT['etd']

destinationRequired = 'Daly City'

for destinationDict in destinationList:
    if destinationDict['destination'] == destinationRequired:
        earliest = None
        for estimate in destinationDict['estimate']:
            if earliest is None or estimate['minutes'] < eariest:
                earliest = estimate['minutes']
        print("Next train to {0}: {1} minutes".format(destinationRequired, earliest))
        break

else:
    print("No trains to {0}".format(destinationRequired))
```

Note there are more Pythonic ways to do this, and the code example above does not follow PEP8, but I think it is important you understand the basic logic of how to do what you want rather than a complex Python one-liner.

You do not document the JSON object format, so I don't think it is safe to assume the list of trains to destination will be in order, therefore the safest is to step through each one and find the earliest.  It isn't even clear if more than one train will ever be returned in the list, in which case a simple [0] would be sufficient rather than stepping through each one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get json data:

```
import json

# some JSON:
json_data= {'destination': 'Daly City', 'abbreviation': 'DALY', 'limited': '0', 'estimate': [{'minutes': '39', 'platform': '1', 'direction': 'South', 'length': '0', 'color': 'BLUE', 'hexcolor': '#0099cc', 'bikeflag': '1', 'delay': '0'}]}

# parse json_data:
data = json.dumps(json_data)
extract_json = json.loads(data)

print("Destination: "+extract_json["destination"])
print("Minutes: "+extract_json["estimate"][0]["minutes"])
```

Output:

```
Destination: Daly City
Minutes: 39
```